# How to convert smallint to boolean in Symfony Form?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony5

I have an entity that contains a smallint value:

```
#[ORM\Column(type: 'smallint')]
    private $isActive;
```

And when I want to generate a form with `$form = $this->createForm(UserTestType::class, $user)` that uses CheckBox to represent this *isActive* value, I get the following error:
Unable to transform value for property path "isActive": Expected a Boolean.
Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Might look into data transformers: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html
although using a boolean field if you can might be preferrable

Comment: Set the type to *boolean* and run a schema update with `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update`.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not able to use boolean, I must use smallint. But I found a solution that kind of works: i added the 'data' attribute and set it so 'false'. It always overrides the smallint when generating the form. Thanks for the tipps guys!